# Should anonymous users be able to suggest edits?

Tags: discussion, support

I noticed that the "[Community](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)" user had suggested an edit to an existing, accepted, correct [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/27464/753), that resulted in the answer no longer being completely correct.

[Further investigation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/9742) shows that the suggestion had come from an anonymous user, and that it had been approved by a moderator.

I ended up downvoting the answer since it was no longer completely correct, but this feels wrong because it was not edited by the original answerer, or even a registered user.

Should we accept edits from anonymous users? What incentive do they have for providing factual information?

Comment: If the approval was erroneous, then please roll back the edit: you have the reputation to do so.

Comment: Done. Still interested in a discussion though. Although this has probably been discussed before on meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I'd think the main concern with anonymous edits would be spam.  However I don't recall seeing any edits suggested by Anonymous, do they go into the approval queue just like suggestions from other users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previous discussions on [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/):

- [Do we have stats showing that anonymous edits are helpful?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120849)
- [Prevent suggested edits coming from anonymous users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83457)
- ["Anonymous user" trying to destroy posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78899)

From the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/gis/query/60587/suggested-edit-stats-for-anon), our current stats for the approvals and rejections of anonymous suggested edits:

```
Approved Rejected 
-------- -------- 
54       32
```

63% approval rate, not bad (compare to 40% for StackOverflow)!